# Restricting HTTP requests for users

Tags: http

Is it possible to restrict a users upload on a desktop linux machine (debian) so the user can only do HTTP requests with max X amount of bytes?

It would be to prevent the user to upload any type of files from the computer to any server on the Internet.

Comment: what webserver are you running (nginx, apache, lighttpd, other)? what does it serve, is it PHP, Perl, Python? Is it configured as proxy or does it serve the application directly?

Comment: @Bart It's not for a webserver. It's for a desktop linux machine

Comment: ok, but do you run any web serving program, as would be suggested by you mentioning HTTP requests?

Comment: You could run a proxy and have the desktop go through the proxy and limit or prevent what you need

Comment: @Bart Because just need it to be able to do HTTP requests.

Comment: @madmanali93 Can you give me some pointers on what keywords to search for please?

Comment: look at squid proxy possibly. See if that helps with what you need.